# Symfony - Undefined type 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I got many errors similar to this in topic after created entities. Dont't know why cuz use tag seems correct. Using symfony 6.1.

Here is my model:

```php
    namespace App\Entity;

    use App\Repository\MovieRepository;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MovieRepository::class)]
    class Movie
    {
      #[ORM\Id]
      #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
      #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
      private $id;
    }
```

Comment: Seems you solved BUT You should edit your question and add all the stacktrace of the related errors you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MovieRepository::class)]
class Movie
{
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $id;
```

try that

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;

#[Entity(repositoryClass: MovieRepository::class)]
class Movie
{
    #[Id, GeneratedValue, Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int $id;
```

Comment: This works. But this model was automatically created by symfony. Is there a way to change way of creating Models to this?